# Why am I getting an 'AccessDenied' error when trying to use an Amazon Cognito identity pool with 'unauthenticated' access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-kinesis

CloudTrail reports 'unauth_role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: kinesisvideo:CreateStream on resource: ExampleStream4' when we try to use an identity pool configured for 'unauthenticated' access.

Our unauthed role looks like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "kinesisvideo:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
},{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
            "cognito-sync:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }]
```

Any call to kinesisvideo with the assumed role CognitoIdentityCredentials gives the AccessDenied error. I've tweaked the role's permissions around quite a bit, and nothing seems to help.  It seems as if the 'AssumedRole' either doesn't have the roles permission, or they aren't being passed to the request. I've tried other API requests such as ListStreams, and that has the same problem.

IAM Policy Simulator is happy with my policies...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that you have an explicit deny somewhere, e.g. from AWS Organization SCPs?

Comment: Where might I see those?

Comment: You should be able to see all the permissions which apply if you use the Policy Simulator correctly, i.e. if you select the correct role (see step 2 of 'To use the policy simulator (console)' in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) and if you have permission to view all the IAM policies and AWS Organization SCPs (see step 3).